# Difference between N & N+ domain

Tags: notation, definition, natural-numbers

$\{0,1,2,...\}$ is $\mathbb{N}$, and $\{1,2,3,...\}$ is $\mathbb{N}^+$ if I'm not wrong.

Does that mean this author does not want to include $0$ in the function?

[image]

Why some authors include $0$ in Natural numbers $(\mathbb{N})$ when Whole numbers $(\mathbb{W})$ are defined to do  exactly the same.

Comment: The whole numbers aren't taught in most of the world. The naturals are the counting numbers and we start counting at $0$. It's become more popular due to the rise of computers where you can make easy mistakes by initializing at $1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/history-of-0-in-mathbb-n).

Comment: What would that definition say if $n=0$?  $$(x)_{0,k} = x (x+k) (x+2k) \dots (x+(-1)k)$$ Presumably, that means an empty produt with value $1$?  That would be confusing to beginning students, so this author omitted that case in his definition.

Comment: @CyclotomicField We start counting at $1$, not $0$. You have two hands, not one.

Comment: @JohnDouma We start counting at $0$ because that's how many elements the empty set has. If it was $1$ then singletons would have be the smallest set, and they're not.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Are you saying you have one hand? The counting numbers do not start at zero, regardless of how many elements the empty set has.

Comment: @JohnDouma I don't have any hands. What's the number of hands I have? I'll give you a hint - counting starts at $0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField See [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/counting-number.html).

Comment: @JohnDouma This is not an authoritative source. I've already explained to you why counting starts at $0$. Your defiance is unconvincing.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Google it. The counting numbers are taught to kindergarten children. We have two hands: one, two. When we count we start at one. There is not a special definition for mathematicians or set theorists. Your argument that zero is the number of elements of the empty set may be a justification for adding zero to the natural numbers but we haven't redefined the counting numbers. You are suggesting that no one outside of the mathematics discipline knows how to count. That's ridiculous.

Comment: I don't know about you two, but I have 2 hands, my 0th and my 1st!

Comment: @JohnDouma And yet we write $102$ to mean one $100$ then $0$ tens, then $2$ ones. Note that we counted $0$ tens. This happens by the time children can count to $10$. So we do use $0$ to count and immediately even at the kindergarten level. I understand that it's not taught correctly to children but $0$ is in fact when counting starts. People were counting long before they figured out $0$ existed because they tacitly assume it's there. They created zero for their tally stick by acquiring the stick. Also, you are $0$ years old at birth. That's because you start counting at $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Makes sense, Thank you.